# If 2 threads running together, will it coflicts global variable value

Tags: multithreading

If 2 threads running together then how global variable will be updated by both threads. Is that value will be conflicted?

Comment: You should use a `lock` to prevent more than one thread from updating the value at the same time.  How you do this depends on the language/framework you're using.

Comment: Use a lock coupled with your shared data and update the variable only when your thread holds the lock. Of course this applies only if the variable is written at least by one thread. Reading only is ok from many threads without a lock.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/WIN32-Multithreaded-Programming-Aaron-Cohen/dp/1565922964

Answer (score 0):

This would depend entirely on what you are doing with the global variable being accessed by multiple threads.

Unless the global variable is thread-safe, in the sense that the variable is locked during an operation to change it's value, then it seems likely that you could end up with a race condition occurring.

I am not certain which language you are working with, but it may make sense to create an accessor for the variable (such as a property) which is locked whilst changes are being applied.  In C# you could accomplish this easily with the following pseudo-code as an example:

```
private object _LockObject = new object();
private int _SomeProperty;

public int SomeProperty
{
    get { return _SomeProperty; }
    set
    {
        lock (_LockObject)
        {
            _SomeProperty = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The `lock` ensuring that the code to change the value of the variable is thread-safe (because it is locked during each update operation).